# Function that can accept a generator, create a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have a function that can accept a list of numbers, a tuple of numbers, or s string of numbers and a variable, n, and it creates a list of tuples of length n as it iterates over the passed in iterable.

At this point it works as expected:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
# numbers = '123456'


def window(iterable, n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    final = []
    last = len(iterable) - (n - 1)
    for start in range(0, last):
        tup = tuple(numbers[start:start + n])
        final.append(tup)
        start += 1
    return final


print(window(numbers, 2))
print()
print(window(numbers, 3))
print()
print(window(numbers, 4))
```

Sample outputs from the list and string:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6)]
[('1', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '4'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '6')]
[('1', '2', '3'), ('2', '3', '4'), ('3', '4', '5'), ('4', '5', '6')]
[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('2', '3', '4', '5'), ('3', '4', '5', '6')]
```

Now I need to allow the function to accept a generator but still generate the same style output.

Ex:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
squares = (n**2 for n in numbers)
window(squares, 3)
[(1, 4, 9), (4, 9, 16), (9, 16, 25), (16, 25, 36)]
```

If I run this as is, I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

I understand why.  My issue is that all I can think of is 'dumping' the generator output into a list and then running it through the function, which is lame.  It makes no sense to allow a generator as a valid input only to then exhaust it into a list.

I figured out how to identify if a generator is passed in:

```
import types


def window(iterable, n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    final = []
    if isinstance(iterable, types.GeneratorType):
        print('Gen')
    else:
        last = len(iterable) - (n - 1)
        for start in range(0, last):
            tup = tuple(numbers[start:start + n])
            final.append(tup)
            start += 1
        return final
```

But I am stuck as to how to proceed in generating the desired output when a generator is passed in.

Comment: See the duplicate post; the top answer there works on general iterators.

Comment: Using your supplied link I found what I was after.  Thanks.